# Internet connection issue

Tags: windows-vista, networking, dhcp, dell-xps

For some reason this laptop doesn't want to stay connected to the Internet. I have to restart the DHCP client service every time to fix the connection problem.

I didn't have to usually do this. I'm not sure if these problems are connected, but the sound also disconnects itself and I have to enable it back, but everything that was using audio has to be restarted in order to hear it, even the browser. There are no external speakers and I didn't install any new software.

My laptop is an XPS M1530, running Windows Vista.

Comment: Is this WiFi or a physical cable connection? Are you connecting at Home or Work? Are you using Cable, DSL? Are you connecting directly to a Cable/DSL modem, or through a router? What router?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you have the latest drivers from the Dell site?  Any Windows updates recently?  Have seen a Windows update for hardware that caused some issues.

How does the laptop conenct to the Internet?

Comment: no I haven't checked for any of those updates..and it connects wireless, but so does my other laptop thats an hp and has no connection issues

Answer (score 0):

If some aspect of the Windows tcp/ip package has been corrupted, the following command can help:

netsh winsock reset

Just run that from the Run command or a command prompt.  Works for Windows XP service pack 2 and newer OSes.